# Failed to start recording, [TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_ExponentAV.default.requestPermissionsAsync')]

Tags: react-native, audio, expo

when I used expo audio to record audio, always has error:
Failed to start recording, TypeError: undefined is not an object evaluating '_ExponentAV.default.requestPermissionsAsync'
at node_modules\expo\build\environment\react-native-logs.fx.js:27:23 in error
at src\components\Chat\ChatForm.tsx:189:19 in startRecording

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

import { Audio } from "expo-av";

type ChatFormProps = {
  onSend: () => void;
};

const ChatForm: React.FC<ChatFormProps> = ({ onSend }) => {

const [isRecording, setIsRecording] = useState(false);
const [recordTime, setRecordTime] = useState<string>("00:00");

const recording = new Audio.Recording();

  const startRecording = async () => {
    try {
      console.log("Requesting permissions..");
      // console.log(Audio);
      await Audio.requestPermissionsAsync();
      await Audio.setAudioModeAsync({
        allowsRecordingIOS: true,
        playsInSilentModeIOS: true,
      });

      console.log("Starting recording..");
      await recording.prepareToRecordAsync(
        Audio.RECORDING_OPTIONS_PRESET_HIGH_QUALITY
      );
      await recording.startAsync();
      setIsRecording(!isRecording);
      console.log("Recording started");
    } catch (err) {
      console.error("Failed to start recording", err);
    }
  };

  const stopRecording = async () => {
    try {
      console.log("Stopping recording..");
      setIsRecording(!isRecording);
      await recording.stopAndUnloadAsync();
      const uri = recording.getURI();
      console.log("Recording stopped and stored at", uri);
    } catch (err) {
      console.error("Failed to stop recording", err);
    }
  };
}
```

Comment: The native view manager required by name (ExpoVideoView) from NativeViewManagerAdapter isn't exported by expo-modules-core. Views of this type may not render correctly. Exported view managers: [].

Answer (score 0):

try to initialize your recording inside the try bloc

```
const startRecording = async () => {
    try {
      console.log("Requesting permissions..");
      // console.log(Audio);
      await Audio.requestPermissionsAsync();
      await Audio.setAudioModeAsync({
        allowsRecordingIOS: true,
        playsInSilentModeIOS: true,
      });

const recording = new Audio.Recording();

      console.log("Starting recording..");
      await recording.prepareToRecordAsync(
        Audio.RECORDING_OPTIONS_PRESET_HIGH_QUALITY
      );
      await recording.startAsync();
      setIsRecording(!isRecording);
      console.log("Recording started");
    } catch (err) {
      console.error("Failed to start recording", err);
    }
  };

  const stopRecording = async () => {
    try {
      console.log("Stopping recording..");
      setIsRecording(!isRecording);
      await recording.stopAndUnloadAsync();
      const uri = recording.getURI();
      console.log("Recording stopped and stored at", uri);
    } catch (err) {
      console.error("Failed to stop recording", err);
    }
  };
}
```